# Trying to Plot Standard Normal Distribution and t-distribution on same graph

Tags: r, statistics

```
dat <- data.frame(dens = c(rnorm(1000000), rt(1000000, 4)), lines = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 100000))
ggplot(dat, aes(x = dens, fill = lines)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
```

This is my code. I'm trying to plot the two distributions on the same graph.  I only ended up with the t distribution.

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You generate 1,000,000 of each number but then you only repeat a/b 100,000 times each. With vector recycling, you are basically mixing the two groups together and they are being drawn right on top of each other since they are essentially the same. Make sure to use the same number of zeros in all your "large numbers" and you'll see a (slightly) different result. This is basically just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Like one of the comments say, this is basically a typo because you repeat the variables `a` and `b` 100,000 (a hundred thousand) times each, making the normally distributed numbers and the t-distributed numbers mixed up. You will need to set the argument `each=1000000` (a million). Or to avoid confusion with how many zeros should be entered, just use `1e6` which means `1 * 10^6`.